# How to set "shortcut icon" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shortcut, favicon

```
<head>
  <title>Application</title>
  <% link { :rel => "shortcut icon", :href => "/images/favicon.ico" } %>
</head>
```

I can't see the image which i set, What's wrong with the above code? How can i run successfully?

Comment: Why use ERB instead of plain HTML?

Comment: Because then you can take advantage of the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[See doc:](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/favicon_link_tag)

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
favicon_link_tag(source='/favicon.ico', options={})

<%= favicon_link_tag %>
```

generates

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

You may specify a different file in the first argument:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag '/myicon.ico' %>
```

That’s passed to path_to_image as is, so it gives

```
<link href="/myicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
```

The helper accepts an additional options hash where you can override “rel” and “type”.

For example, Mobile Safari looks for a different LINK tag, pointing to an image that will be used if you add the page to the home screen of an iPod Touch, iPhone, or iPad. The following call would generate such a tag:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'mb-icon.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon', :type => 'image/png' %>
```

Method Like

```
def favicon_link_tag(source='/favicon.ico', options={})
  tag('link', {
    :rel  => 'shortcut icon',
    :type => 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon',
    :href => path_to_image(source)
  }.merge(options.symbolize_keys))
end
```